# Error login nodejs > this.password no reconocido con bcrypt

Tags: nodejs, typescript, login, mongoose, bcryptjs

en primer lugar gracias por entrar a la pregunta.

Todo este código funciona okai salvo por: userSchema.methods.isValidPassword

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    email: string,
    password: string
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        requried: true
    }
});

userSchema.pre<IUser>('save', async function (next) {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
        this.password = hashedPassword;
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
});

userSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password: string) {
    try {
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, (this as IUser).password);
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
};

export default userSchema;
```

En el estado actual el programa si me compila pero no realiza la comparacion de la contraseña introducida por el cliente y la guardada en la base de datos hasheada correctamente.

Si introduzco el hash guardado en la bbdd en la pantalla de login > BINGO! Si logro acceder por lo tanto no está "deshasheando" la contraseña bien para poder compararla con la introducida por el cliente.

En resumen, no consigo loguear a nadie a noser que la contraseña no esté hasheada en la bbdd.

¿Alguna idea para solucionar este issue? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ahí sólo veo el método que hace la comprobación, pero viendo que tu problema es el obtener el usuario, puedo afirmar lo siguiente:

Cuando haces un compare, le mandas dos parámetros, una contraseña en texto plano y otra encriptada, y el método comparte lo que hace es encriptar la contraseña plana y compararla con la encriptada. No puedes mandarle una encriptada, porque el asunto de tenerla encriptada es para mayor seguridad en caso de filtración de datos o hackeos.

Si añadieras el método donde compruebas eso, podría darte una respuesta más acertada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente solucioné esto creando una función a parte en vez de una función interna del schema, en vez de utilizar this.password simplemente paso a la función la contraseña introducida por el usuario y la contraseña de la bd, en su interior uso bcrypt compare y funciona sin problemas.